# Reference app in express middleware

Tags: express

Supposing we have some middleware in `express 4.0`:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // ... i want app here. except this 
  // method is imported from another file
  // so app isn't in scope.
});
```

Is there any way to get the `app` object?

I'm writing several custom middleware packages and I keep finding myself needing to reference app (from another file of course). I'm doing hokey things like this:

`app.use(fabMiddleware(app));`

Which is really a high-order function:

```
const fabMiddleware = (app) => {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // ... now i can use app
  }
}
modue.exports = fabMiddleware;
```

Does perhaps `this`, `req` or `res` have a reference to `app`?

Comment: The way you show your first block of code, `app` is in scope where you say you want to use it so you can just directly reference it.  So, that apparently does not reflect what your actual question is or you overlooked the simplest possible solution.

Comment: Didn't overlook it. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can access the `app` instance without needing to explicitly pass it in. Simply call `req.app` or `res.app` to get access to it.

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.app

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.app